# Grunt.Js (+ Yeoman) - Copy bower files when building

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I used yeoman 1.0 RC1 to generate webapp. However when I build my script none of the dependencies (besides require.js) are copied to the `dist/bower_components` directory. Here is my generated [Gruntfile.js](https://gist.github.com/telemetrik/6037427) and my [bower.json](https://gist.github.com/telemetrik/6037434). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

When you use Usemin blocks, such as...

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/package/file.js"></script>
( etc... )
<!-- endbuild -->
```

...you don't need to copy over `bower_components/` to `dist/`. During the build process, blocks like the one above will be concatenated, minified, and stuffed into a file that matches what's in the opening comment (in the above case, it would be `scripts/vendor.js`). Additionally, it is prefixed with a unique hash, like `scripts/3fa3f7z.vendor.js` for cache-busting.

My guess for a solution would be to move your `<script></script>`s into a Usemin block. You can use as little or as many of them as you'd like.

Comment: I'm using Require.JS, so all my dependencies are minified within main.js.